# How to set a default application window size

Tags: macos, swiftui

Basically the title. I am wondering how its possible to set the default window size so that when a the user opens the app or opens a new window of that app its a specified size and not a giant window with a bunch of blank space surrounding it. Using the `.frame()` modifier would work but it doesn't let me resize the window or put it into split screen mode which is useless. I am using SwiftUI and building the app for macOS only. Additionally I am not using application delegate. I am using this:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I should also add that I tried to add the `.resizable()` modifier to my content view but it throws the error `Value of type 'some View' has no member 'resizable'`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From the Apple Tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-macos-app, add `.frame(minWidth: 700, minHeight: 300)`

Comment: Okay thank you that lets me resize it however if I press cmd+N or just open a new window (of the app) it still opens the default huge size with a bunch of extra space